# How can I create an activity feed using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I generated scaffolds and add the following to my models

```
User
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
end

Post
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order ('created_at DESC')}
end

Link
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC')}
end

Image
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> {order ('created_at DESC')}
end
```

how can I get these posts to display on user's homepage

Comment: Try avoiding default_scope since on CREATE transactions they will default these as well which might get you frustrated quite a bit from time to time.

Comment: Also I don't see any class definitions or ActiveRecord::Base inheritance where will the posts come from? try some basic rails tutorials first.

Comment: I know about the ActiveRecord::Base only I was using a phone. thanks for noticing and I'll try to avoid the default_scope. great tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a common request to have a user activity feed on a website. You can use [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem. 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?view=asciicast is a tutorial by rBates.

Comment: The railscast are great, I also 407 building activity feed from scratch. I just had to subscribe for the procasts. very helpful but I am looking for a way to display the actual post. like when a user posts an image I want the image to show.

Answer (score -4):

First and foremost, I’d like to be open and say that I am an employee of Stream, an API for building scalable news and activity feeds – much like you would see on Facebook, Instagram, and other social media applications.

From my extensive experience as a developer and consultant and continued research and self-education, Stream’s technology stack is extremely effective and competitive. You can get a news or activity feed up and running in a fraction of the time than it would take you to build out your own infrastructure (Cassandra clusters, queuing mechanisms, etc.).

While you can certainly build everything in-house, I would recommend giving our 5 minute tutorial a shot at https://getstream.io/get_started/#intro. We have SDKs for various languages, including Ruby.

Best of luck and feel free to reach out to support@getstream.io with any questions. Cheers!